# Add UserControl to MainWindow depend on logged account

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls

I would like to ask you, how can I add/show particular user control in MainWindow but with dependency who is currently logged to my app. If employee show EmployeeModule, if Admin show AdminModule.
I have LoginDialog. If UserId and Pass correct, then check in the database and get Access. If Access="EE" then:

```
Dim mainmen As New EmployeeModule
                    MainMenu.Children.Add(mainmen)
                    Grid.SetRow(mainmen, 0)
```

I know how to do that for each module in codebehind but I need to set x:Name and x:FieldModifier for each because I need access to each usercontrol from MainWindow. Like that:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainMenu" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,10,10,0" Height="694" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <local:EmployeeMainMenu x:Name="emploman" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
    </Grid>
```

And then I'm using "emploman" name to get into the usercontrol.

Is it possible to do it in xaml (add  for each item with Visibility which will change from e.g Hidden to Visible if Access="EE" (in this case).

A litle bit messy but I hope you will understand my point...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is for you to use `DataTemplate`s. If you are unfamiliar with these, then you should read the [Data Templating Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. Basically, if you declare a `DataTemplate` for each type of data that you have and *do not set the `x:Key` property values on them*, then the Framework will implicitly apply them to your data when it sees it:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:Employee}">
    <!-- Define your Employee XAML here -->
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:Admin}">
    <!-- Define your Admin XAML here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Now add a property of type `object` (better if this was a base class for your data model classes):

```
public object DataItem { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here
```

Then you can data bind that to a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding DataItem}" />
```

Finally in your code behind, you can do this and WPF will take care of the rest:

```
if (Access == "EE") DataItem = new Employee();
else DataItem = new Admin();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarifications! for that ContentControl - should I put it in <Grid> </Grid>?

Comment: Why not? You can put it anywhere you like.

Comment: @Sheridan copy/paste mistake I assume in the second DataTemplate. It should be YourPrefix:Admin for the DataType.

Comment: great. And one last quetion (I hope ;) ) - about the code behind (converted to vb off'c). public object DataItem { get; set; } I add it to MainWindow.xaml.vb. 

if (Access == "EE") DataItem = new Employee();
else DataItem = new Admin();

I will add it to my loginDialog yes?

Comment: @user2678787, just think about it... it's up to you where you want to put it. You could add the property to the object that is set as the `DataContext` for `MainWindow`. The code will obviously go wherever the property goes... otherwise, how else could the code call the property?